# Wordpress Visual Editor is not working

Tags: bug

From 2-3 days, Wordpress Visual text editor is not working. I cannot type anything, cannot press any button. Nothing is working in the "Visual" section. But "Text" (html) editor is working perfectly. When i type something in "text"" (html) editor, it do not appear in text editor.

I tried to disable and enable all plugins.

Here is the picture of my visual editor [image]

Comment: If you disable all plugins, and change your theme to a WordPress default theme (TwentyEleven, TwentySixteen, etc) does it work with everything to default? Turn the plugins back on one by one, and test after each one. If that doesn't work, open up your browser developer tools and look in the console tab - what errors are displayed?

Answer (score 0):

One reason why it's not working would be the using a old version of Visual Editor in a newer version of WordPress. So, you have two choices now either downgrading WordPress or upgrading Visual Editor. Give it a try, Hope it might work for you.

Comment: I am using latest version. It was working fine but before 2-3 days it stopped working, i did not update anything.